# Discord.js command only working once after running it

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I have a code

```js
client.once('message', message => {
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if (command === 'say') {
        if (!args.length) {
            return message.channel.send('You didn\'t provide anything to say');
        }
        
        message.channel.send(`${args}`);
    }
});
```

But if i run the say command once it stops working after that is there any way to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.once()` only runs, well... once. You should use `.on()` to listen to every incoming message:

```js
client.on('message', message => {
 //...
```